# fluidbootstraptheme Passing data from controllers to view Configuration section

Tags: typo3, fluid, flux

I am using the fluidbootstraptheme because is easy to use, extend, etc... until now that I am trying to pass data from the controller to the view Configuration section.

View Glyphicons.html:

```
<f:section name="Configuration">
        <flux:form id="glyphicons" options="{useTypoScript: 0, group: 'Bootstrap', icon: '{f:uri.resource(path: \'Icons/bootstrap/glyphicons_101_italic.png\')}'}">
            <flux:field.select name="header" items="{glyph}" />
        </flux:form>
    </f:section>
```

Content Controller

```
public function glyphiconsAction() {
        $this->view->assign(glyph', 'value1,value2,value3');
}
```

Even I have tried array('value1','value2','value3') or '{foo: bar}' with no results

Comment: In the above you have misspelled assign, you have "assing" instead. Is that what does it?

Comment: yes, because I was wriiting not really copying the code, it is something like this $this->view->assign(glyph', 'value1,value2,value3');